# Program an Arduino from a Raspberry Pi using UART

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to program an Arduino mounted on a breadboard using a Raspberry Pi.
For the setup of the Arduino I have been following [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone) tutorial, except from the USB-serial device. Instead I have the Raspberry Pi connected through a level converter. I designed the level converter myself using a 4066 analog switch and an op-amp as a voltage follower to supply a stable 3.3V voltage. The 3.3V from the Pi is converted to 5V on the Arduino pins, and vice versa. I am not getting any response from running avrdude in the shell or through the Arduino IDE on the Pi.

Both the Pi and the Arduino are driving their TX pins to high value (3.3V and 5V). The Arduino has been flashed with a bootloader in a stk500 development board. The command I have been running is:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega8 -carduino -P/dev/ttyAMA0 -b9600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build4533291593992176675.tmp/sketch_mar21a.cpp.hex:i
```

LED connected to pin13 flashed aproximately every 6 seconds.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the Raspberry Pi talking to the Arduino?

Comment: Why not run the Arduino at 3.3V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly stumped. First thing I'd try is just to check that RX/TX communication is working. Write a simple program to read and write on arduino pins 2 and 3 and something similar on the PI.

Other things to look at  http://arduino.cc/en/Main/StandaloneAssembly. You might be able to do things using AVR see http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Programmer.

There is a new arduino stack exchange https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ it might be worth asking there.